# VBA - test if a value is a valid selection for a PivotField

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table, vba

For a pivot table (pt1) on Sheet1, I use VBA to change the value of a filter field (filterfield) using the code below. Let's say values for field can be A, B or C

```
Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("pt1").PivotFields("filterfield").CurrentPage = "A"
```

Occasionally, and let's say randomonly for the purposes of this question, A, B or C will not be a valid selection for filterfield. When VBA attempts to change the field, it throws a run-time error. I want to avoid this.

How can I check if my values are valid for filterfield before I run the code above? I would like to avoid using On Error and VBA does not have try/catch functionality..

Comment: Wasn't this just posted on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/922321/excel-vba-invalid-value-for-pivotfield)?

Comment: You can iterate through the `PivotFields("filterField").PivotItems` and check if the desired value exists in that collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through the `PivotItems` and check the `Name` against your test.

```
Sub CheckIfPivotFieldContainsItem()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = Sheet1.PivotTables(1)

    Dim test_val As Variant
    test_val = "59"

    Dim pivot_item As PivotItem
    For Each pivot_item In pt.PivotFields("C").PivotItems
        If pivot_item.Name = test_val Then
            Debug.Print "MATCHES"
        End If
    Next pi

End Sub
```

**Relevant data** shows that a match should exist and indeed it returns `MATCHES`.

[image: pivot data]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a helper function and do this without looping values you may use visual basic OnErrorResumeNext trick.

```
Private Function hasPivotItem(pField As PivotField, value As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    hasPivotItem = Not IsNull(pField.PivotItems(value))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

' somewhere in your vba program
Debug.Print hasPivotItem(ptTable.PivotFields("Level"), "1")
Debug.Print hasPivotItem(ptTable.PivotFields("Level"), "-123")
```

Comment: Kudos on avoiding loops! But why is `hasPivotItem = False` (at least in the original edit) needed?

Comment: @LWC We must initialize a desired default return value before calling `pField.PivotItems(str)`. We ignore errors(OnErrorResumeNext) so return value is never set on unknown field, we want to default FALSE.

Comment: What can I say, when the field doesn't exist it seems to return false even without this preliminary declaration.