# Test If A Pivot Field Is Showing on A Pivot Table VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a Pivot Table with a Report Filter field A, Column Labels field B and Row Labels field C.

With VBA what is a simple way to check if these fields are showing on pivot table?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have already tried? Please put some effort into it yourself first. You can use Excels "record macro" functionality to get started.

Comment: @brax I used the second function here sucessfully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578880/vba-test-if-a-value-is-a-valid-selection-for-a-pivotfield, but it only finds the pivot item.   I don't really know where to start to determine if a field is active on the pivot table.

Comment: Do you want to check if they are anywhere in the PivotTable, or do you want to confirm that A is in the Report Filter field, B is in the Columns field, and C is in the Row field?

Comment: @jeffreyweir I have the pivot table setup, so I want to confirm each field is where it is suppose to be exactly (i.e. A = Report Filter).   In following steps I apply filters to the fields so if the fields are not in the pivot table my code breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check all three of them at once using something like this:

```
Sub CheckFields()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SomePivotTable")

For Each pf In pt.VisibleFields
    If intr("|A|B|C|", "|" & pf.Name & "|") > 0 Then
        'the pf is in the Pivot
    Else
        'the pf is not in the Pivot
    End If
Next pf
End Sub
```

...or you can just test what pf.orientation returns. If it's anything but xlDataField or xlHidden then you are good to go.

[image]