# How to make this not repetitive?

Tags: excel, vba

code below searches specific name in items in pivot table filter and filters by that name if found. then changes column1 to that name, and calls another method. it does this for 6 names that always will be the same. how do I limit repetitiveness? should this be done any different?

```
For Each pvtitem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").PivotItems
   If pvtitem.Name = "BUN" Then
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
        = "BUN"
    Column1 = "AA"
    Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
    Exit For
   End If
   Next


   For Each pvtitem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").PivotItems
   If pvtitem.Name = "CAX" Then
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
        = "CAX"
      Column1 = "AQ"
    Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
    Exit For
   End If
   Next

   For Each pvtitem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").PivotItems
   If pvtitem.Name = "CNF" Then
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
        = "CNF"
      Column1 = "BG"
    Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
    Exit For
   End If
   Next

   For Each pvtitem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").PivotItems
   If pvtitem.Name = "CVN" Then
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
        = "CVN"
      Column1 = "BW"
    Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
    Exit For
   End If
   Next

   For Each pvtitem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").PivotItems
   If pvtitem.Name = "GMN" Then
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
        = "GMN"
      Column1 = "DS"
    Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
    Exit For
   End If
   Next

   For Each pvtitem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").PivotItems
   If pvtitem.Name = "XCD" Then
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
        = "XCD"
      Column1 = "EY"
    Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
    Exit For
   End If
   Next
```

Comment: Look in to Select Case. Also, it looks like they always do `Call Brand(...)`. You can remove that from each `If` statement and just put it once at the end.

Comment: I can not put at end because its different every time. I am filtering and copying values into specific cells in another worksheet after I filter.

Comment: Can you clarify how it's different?  It looks like each time it's `Call Brand(Range1, Column1)`?

Comment: Create a `pvtNameArray` with each of your 6 names and loop such that `pvtItem.Name = pvtNameArray(name)`

Comment: The data is different bc there is a different name being filtered and different data in the pivot and the column I am pasting to in the other worksheet is different

Comment: Duplicated code often indicate that a function/sub may be used.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect example for the use of `Select Case`:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim pvtitem As PivotItem
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim Column1 As String

    'Set Range1 = <your range>
    'If necessary, you can set this as part of the select case along with Column1

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code")
        For Each pvtitem In .PivotItems
            Column1 = vbNullString
            Select Case UCase(pvtitem.Name)
                Case "BUN": Column1 = "AA"
                Case "CAX": Column1 = "AQ"
                Case "CNF": Column1 = "BG"
                Case "CVN": Column1 = "BW"
                Case "GMN": Column1 = "DS"
                Case "XCD": Column1 = "EY"
            End Select
            If Len(Column1) > 0 Then
                .CurrentPage = pvtitem.Name
                Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
            End If
        Next pvtitem
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it this way:

```
workitems = Array("BUN-AA","CAX-AQ","CNF-BG","CVN-BW","GMN-BS","XCD-EY")
For Each workitem In workitems
    nm = Split(workitem, "-")(0)
    clm = Split(workitem, "-")(1)
    For Each pvtitem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").PivotItems
        If pvtitem.Name = nm Then
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
            = nm
            Column1 = clm
            Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

It's easy to expand later, just add more workitems.

Comment: nice, Also re the 2nd for each, the reason I had a for in the first place was to check if the nm exits. is there any way to do this without going through all of them? is this the best way?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578880 - there is a way using error trapping within a standalone function.